# Local host is different from server

Tags: javascript

The project I'm working on functions differently on the localhost than the server. I'm even running the localhost on the remote desktop that has the server. Firebug in Firefox shows an error in the javascript when I'm debugging on the server but it was a simple syntax error that I already fixed and it works fine on the localhost. I already tried clearing the cache on the browser and rebuilding the project. I'm pretty sure it's the unchanged javascript that is causing the problem but I can't figure out how to update my fixes.

Comment: Try to re-upload the files to the server.

Comment: Did you clear all caches? On the server, but also in your browser?

Comment: I fixed it! Thank you. I had forgotten to rebuild the whole project. I was just rebuilding that one file. It had been a while since I had worked on this project and I forgot I had to do that when I made changes to the js functions.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the file, request it and then add it back to see if the response changes